# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25 SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a couple one to many relationships in spring between my classes. And when i try to get all my data an error like infinite recursion, here is the whole error message.

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
```

i have 2 classes that are connected with each other with OneToMany Relationship

**USER CLASS**

```
public class User  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "User")
    private List<Conversation> Conversation;
```

**CONVERSATION CLASS**

```
public class Conversation {
     @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "User_id")
     private User User;
```

**Results screeshot**

[Results screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tnxo.png)

I don't know why it happens, but maybe it is because of the relationship with the class Failure.

**Repository Class**

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM `conversation` WHERE 1")
public List<Conversation> findAllConv();
```

**Controller class**

```
 @Autowired
        private ConversationRepository conv;
        
        @GetMapping("/GetAllConversation")
        public List<Conversation> getAllConv()
        {
            return conv.findAllConv();
        }
```

**Full Trace**

```
2021-05-14 12:58:57.306 ERROR 1540 --- [nio-8020-exec-1] w.s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView : Cannot render error page for request [/survey/GetAllConversation/] and exception [Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.club.entities.User_$$_jvstf65_b["conversation"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->org.club.entities.Conversation["user"]-
```

Comment: That is definitely not the whole error message. It should start with either `Exception in thread` or the name of an exception class, not `at`. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , and help us help you by enabling us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: In which step/ for what are you using Jackson here? Do you have a Rest Controller and want to serialize your JPA entities to JSON? Or is it another use case?

Answer (score 2):

When using relations in general, you can adjust the "fetch" and "cascade" type. Fetching means, if all entries related to the one you want to load are loaded as well while cascading relates to operations on the current entry being passed down to relating objects.

Edit1: I would suggest you try setting the `fetch` type to lazy at least for the `Conversation` class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Apart from that, I would suggest using repositories that inherit from `CrudRepository` so you can use derived queries.

Edit2: After seeing the stack trace the problem becomes clear. Jackson is trying to bind the `Conversation` object to JSON but encounters an endless loop because of the Conversation reference in the `User` class.

There are two ways to solve this. If you still want to insert the `User` object referenced by a `Conversation` you can add the `@JsonIgnore` Annotation.

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "User")
private List<Conversation> Conversation;
```

If you don't care about the user at all, then you could also add this to the user reference in the conversation object:

```
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "User_id")
private User User;
```

If you later encounter problems, you could also think about mapping the `Conversation` objects returned by your repository to specific data transfer objects which are specifically made for the JSON mapping.

Comment: i have added the repository and controller class

Comment: @Grimalus no change :/

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace, as @Karl Knechtel suggested. It's hard to debug from afar without the exact knowledge of the error.

Comment: Done i added the stack trace

Comment: I edited my original answer. This should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Judgind by the stacktrace, and the data model the problem lies in the fact, that you have two way relationship between User and Converstaion classes.

User have a list of Conversation items, which then link back to the user. When serializing, this creates an **infinite loop**:

serialize user -> serialize his conversations -> serialize coversation.user -> serialize his conversations etc.

One way to avoid this is to annotate the User field in converstaion with `@JsonIgnore`, this way when serializing user, you'll get his conversations, but since the reference back will be ignored by Jackson, you won't get the error from the stacktrace.

The exception message is pretty clear here:
**Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:** org.club.entities.User_$$_jvstf65_b["conversation"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->org.club.entities.Conversation["user"]-

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by the following thing.
First I have two classes.

```java
public class Entite implements Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int entiteId;
    private String entiteName;
    private String affectation, Wilayas, type, Mougattaa;
// @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entite", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JsonIgnore
// @JoinTable(name = "dep_ent_TABLE",
// joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entite_id"),
// inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
// )
// ( cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Department> departments;

// private Department department;
    protected Entite() {
        departments = new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

and the other class is

```java
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int departmentId;
    @Column(name = "department_name")
    private String departmentName;
    @Column(name = "department_url")
    private String departmentUrl;
    @Column(name = "department_titre")
    private String departmentTitre;
// @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @ManyToOne
// @JsonIgnore
// @JsonManagedReference
    private Entite entite;

    public Department() {
        // entites = new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

By adding `@JsonIgnore`
above this line of the code

```
private Set<Department> departments;
```

makes it work.